Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip'
i have error on my project flutter in my vscode
android/app/build.gradle 
like this

Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip'.
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Build file
Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.

the error said requires Java 11. but my java version is latest recommended version of Java.
Even so, my project can still run well. but I want to fix this error
enter image description here
can u guys help me how to fix this issue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
